# Facebook stream publish to app's wall, user's news feed AND user's wall

Tags: facebook

below is my FB api call in PHP5, which successfully publishes my feed to the **App's Wall** and the **user's news feed**.

```
$facebook->api_client->stream_publish($message, $attachment, $action_links, APP_ID, $facebook_uid);
```

I'd like to know if there's a way to publish the same feed to the **app's wall**, **user's news feed** AND ***user's own wall*** - all three places in one publish.

I could send the stream twice (once for the app and once for user's wall) but it gets hard to manage the comments/likes later on.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Posting to a user's feed will also have that Post appear in the users' friends' News Feeds - so two of the things you're asking for are already there via one publish.

Posting to the app's wall is something you probably shouldn't be doing from a user's perspective, as it won't be seen by anyone except people browsing the app's profile page's wall. If you do need to do this for some reason, just make a second publish call and change the `target_id` parameter to the page ID (old REST API) or Post to `/<app page id>/feed` if using the Graph API